# Onclick issue with jquery .toggle() and jquery .load()

Tags: jquery

Why does the following require me to click twice for it to open and twice for it to close?

And when i replace toggle with what i'd prefer to have, fadetoggle, why does it break the AJAX request to load in (this.href)?

```
    $(document.body).ready(function () {
          $("li.span3 a").click(function (e) {
              $('.content').toggle().load(this.href);
              e.preventDefault();
              $("li.span3 a").click(function(e){
                  $('.content').toggle();
                  e.preventDefault();
              });
          });

    });
```

Comment: `.toggle` has been deprecated. You should not use it anymore.

Comment: According the jQuery API documentation, in fact new features were just added to the .toggle method in version 1.8. So no, I do not think it is being deprecated anytime soon. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @iGanja: It is listed here: [Api docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/)

Comment: that is a VERY specific override signature for binding multiple handlers. This is NOT that signature. This toggle is from the basic core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is embed an event handler within another, so the second is not defined until you initiate the first:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("li.span3 a").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();                  
          $('.content').toggle()
          [some other check here] {
             $('.content').load(this.href);
          }
       });
    });
```